# How to sort data based on jsonb column values

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table with 4 columns where one of the columns (id) is of data type jsonb. I need to have the values sorted in this column. 
sample data:

```
name     age    zip      id
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc      25     11111    ["2722", "2855", "3583", "2722", "2855"]
```

```sql
SELECT (t2.id ->> 'x')::numeric 
FROM table t2
```

I was trying to get the sorted values and then use it in inner query but the above query returns null.

I would like the result to show up as:

```
name     age    zip      id
----------------------------------------------------------------
abc      25     11111    ["2722", "2722", "2855", "2855","3583"]
```

Comment: Your JSON value does not contain a key named `'x'` (it does not contain any top-level key) so obviously `id ->> 'x'` returns null. What you want to do, can't easily be done. You need to unnest the array and then sort it while you aggregate it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name said, you have to break apart your array and then put it back together:

```
SELECT name, 
       age, 
       zip, 
       jsonb_agg(ids ORDER BY ids) 
FROM (
  SELECT name, 
         age, 
         zip, 
         jsonb_array_elements(id) as ids 
  FROM test) AS sub
GROUP BY name, age, zip;
 name | age |  zip  |                jsonb_agg
------+-----+-------+------------------------------------------
 abc  |  25 | 11111 | ["2722", "2722", "2855", "2855", "3583"]
```